# Weird characters using vim on iterm2 on Mavericks

Tags: iterm2

When I start vim in iterm2 on Mavericks I get the following weird characters
[image: iterm running vim]

More of the same appears somewhat randomly when I type. Possibly more when i type brackets

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Yosemite, the problem disappeared for me. Perhaps something dodgy in my environment that got cleaned up on upgrade